# How to define object's property type depending on a key name

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I want to achieve:

- if property name starts with `on`, it's type must be a `Function`
- in all other cases the type is `boolean`

My first naive approach was:

```js
interface Props {
  [key: `on${string}`]: Function; // error: `on${string}`' index type 'Function' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'boolean'.ts(2413)
  [key: string]: boolean;
}
```

My second try was:

```js
type EventName = `on${string}`;

interface Props {
  [K: EventName | string]: typeof K extends EventName ? Function : boolean;
}

const props: Props = {
  asd: true,
  onClick: () => {}, // error: Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
};
```

So is it possible to achieve this, maybe in a different way?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't 100% possible, since the code couldn't be fully checked. If `s` contains a `string` there is no real way to prevent it from containing a `string` starting with `on`. This is why the `string` index signature needs to be compatible with all defined props.

```
let s = "onClick" as string;
let v = props[s] // typed as boolean, is actually onClick
```

One version to get around this warning (although not to make it safe) is to use an intersection instead of an interface. This will allow access to properties to work as you want them to, but creation of such objects requires a type assertion, as the underlying incompatibility is still there

```
type Props = {
  [key: `on${string}`]: Function; 
} & {
  [key: string]: boolean;
}

const props: Props = {
  asd: true,
  onClick: () => {}, 
} as any as Props;

props.onClick // Function
props.ssss // boolean
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgbQGsIQAuKAAwQDsASTZYOAS2oHMBfCgXXIDEArtQDGwZjQDcUbBygAyLLgLEyURi3a8oAIwQIANhACG1CTOzZhNRlDCIU5eElQYceI8gAm5JgIgAaJRoAYX1mYUJyAAoASnQAPiwOf2lZDygTEAzUJxQzbDtnADoQsIioAHoKqEERMRoC+2Qi5FbUKp09QxMgA)

For creation, to avoid the `any` type assertio, and get some validation for object creation, we could use a function that validates that any keys not prefixed with `on`  are of type boolean:

```
function makeProps<T extends Record<`on${string}`, Function>>(o: T & Record<Exclude<keyof T, `on${string}`>, boolean>) {
    return o as Props;
}
const props: Props = makeProps({
  asd: true,
  onClick: () => {}, 
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgbQGsIQAuKAAwQDsASTZYOAS2oHMBfCgXXIDEArtQDGwZjQDcUbBygAyLLgLEyURi3a8oAIwQIANhACG1CTOzYAZkNHjqUALZHi8JMgA8AFSgQAHsAhqABNUACUIYQQ4IPcqOgYmVk4KABooQRExGgA+bIAKBHJvBXDI6PcAUV9hfQEgiHcVBEsoTzS4+nUkrmy03QNjamyASkU8PDgIYAE4ewQoI1RXFDMObEjqRigwRBRyZdQMJxdd5DycPEWg8iYBCBSlGgBhfWZhQnI80bRsrA40mTDCw7NwAOmer3eUAA9ND0jYstRsCCUKDkOjULCdHpDCYgA)

The safer solution would be to make the `boolean` and the `Function` keys disjoint by using a prefix for the `boolean` props as well.

```
type Props = {
  [key: `on${string}`]: (...a: any[]) => any; 
  [key: `flag${string}`]: boolean;
}

const props: Props = {
  onClick: () => {}, 
  flagRaiseClick: true
}

props.onClick // Function
props.flagRaiseClick // boolean
```

Comment: Hmm, I definitely need the safety. The last solution is closest to what I need, but without the second prefix) I thought the typechecker could test each case in order they appear, so the top one evaluates first and checks whether string starts with `on`.